# How can I test my trained model on a completely new dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation, classifier

### Preface

I have an annotated text dataset on hate speech. Simply put, the dataset consists of a column called `text` which includes a piece of text, and a column called `label` which can be either `0` (non-hateful) or `1` (hateful).  Let's call this dataset `Dataset A`.

I am using this dataset to train a very simple classifier using Logistic Regression. Code:

```
dataset_1_df = pd.read_csv(d_1_path, sep='\t')

text = dataset_1_df.text   
X = text
y = dataset_1_df['label'].astype(int)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.1)

clf = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(max_features=10000, ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(norm='l2')),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression()),
])

clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_preds = clf.predict(X_test)
```

This classifier works fine. I can produce a classification report like this:

```
report = classification_report(y_test, y_preds)
print(report)
```

Which outputs:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.87      0.70      0.78       410
           1       0.94      0.98      0.96      2069

    accuracy                           0.93      2479
   macro avg       0.91      0.84      0.87      2479
weighted avg       0.93      0.93      0.93      2479
```

And I can now make predictions like this:

```
print(clf.predict(['I hate you']))
print(clf.predict_proba(['I hate you']))
```

Which outputs:

```
[1]
[[0.0749381 0.9250619]]
```

---

### My Question

I have **another** dataset, let's call this `Dataset B`, independent to `Dataset A`. `Dataset B` is also an annotated text dataset on hate speech with the same columns.

What I want to do is to test the model I trained using `Dataset A` on `Dataset B`. I.e., I want to produce a classification report on my model's performance on `Dataset B`. Can I do that? If yes, how?

**Clarification:** I do **not** want to retrain my model using `Dataset B`. I want to see how good its performance is on the new dataset.

---

#### Similar Questions

There is [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33256/how-to-apply-machine-learning-model-to-new-dataset) question that looks similar based on the title but does not ask what I'm asking.

There's is also [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58766/how-to-use-a-a-trained-model) question which asks how to make predictions. However, I know how to make predictions, what I want to do is to ***test*** my trained model on a totally new dataset.

Comment: You can just iterate over the new samples (second dataset) and do "predict". Then, you compare the assigned labels with the ground truths. You can then calculate any score you want.

Comment: @t_e_o I was actually implementing this right now but it feels a bit 'dirty'. I would guess that there exists a more professional way to produce such a report.

Comment: Why not just `clf.predict(Dataset_B_drop_label)`?  How is `Dataset B` different from `X_test`?

Comment: @BenReiniger Because I'm stupid. It is as simple as that! Can you please write this an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: It seems then that the second question you linked actually does answer your question.  I'll vote to close as duplicate, then.